# How to count distinct non-missing rows in R using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, data-wrangling

```
library(dplyr)
mydat <- data.frame(id = c(123, 111, 234, "none", 123, 384, "none"),
                    id2 = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4))
> mydat
    id id2
1  123   1
2  111   1
3  234   1
4 none   2
5  123   2
6  384   3
7 none   4
```

I would like to count the number of unique `id`s for each `id2` in `medal`. However, for the `id` that is `none`, I do not want to count it.

```
> mydat %>% group_by(id2) %>% summarise(count = n_distinct(id))
# A tibble: 4 × 2
    id2 count
  <dbl> <int>
1     1     3
2     2     2
3     3     1
4     4     1
```

Using this mistakenly counts `none`. The desired output should be

```
> mydat %>% group_by(id2) %>% summarise(count = n_distinct(id))
# A tibble: 4 × 2
    id2 count
  <dbl> <int>
1     1     3
2     2     1
3     3     1
4     4     0
```

Comment: Put a `filter(id != "none")` before your `summarize()`. Or use `n_distinct(id[id != "none"])` if you don't want to filter your whole data.

Comment: But then that gets rid of row for `id2` = 4 entirely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
mydat %>% group_by(id2) %>% 
  summarise(
    count = n_distinct(id),
    wanted = n_distinct(id[id != "none"])
  )
# # A tibble: 4 × 3
#     id2 count wanted
#   <dbl> <int>  <int>
# 1     1     3      3
# 2     2     2      1
# 3     3     1      1
# 4     4     1      0
```